# Best way to preserve choco-chip cookies: food saver?

Tags: baking, cookies, storage

Hi cookie perfectionists!

What is the best way to preserve chocolate chip cookies for one-week? Here's my short-list:

1. Vacuum-sealed mason jars?
2. Vacuum-sealed bags? (will deform the cookies)
3. Any of the above w/ refrigeration?
4. w/o refrigeration?

What's your experience of the longest you stored a cookie, gave it to someone, and they said it was "really good!"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I have to say that I very rarely have to store cookies for more than a few days...

However, if it must be done, then I find that they keep well for 7-10 days (depending on the recipe) in an airtight container on the counter. I've never tried vacuum sealing the container. I think that that would lead to explosive cookie crumbles when you tried to open it.

If you simply want fresh cookies over a long period of time, the best way in my opinion is to make the dough, roll into balls, and freeze the balls. They will last for 2-3 months in the fridge, and you can bake as many or as few as you like straight from frozen (add an extra minute to the baking time). There will be freshly baked cookies in the amount of time it takes you to make the coffee.

Comment: Thanks! Marked this one because it was first. Though it's the baking step that I wish to expedite. Alternatively, how many days does a cookie remain decent to sell? I make my cookies sort of "medium well" but no internal doughiness, but not crunchy either.

Comment: @wearashirt Exactly how long depends on the recipe. I have a chocolate chip cookie that starts drying slightly after 2 days, and one that tastes fresh for 10. As for selling, that's up to you. Make a batch, and try one every day. The sell-by date is the day before the day when you no longer would pay for that cookie.

Answer (score 1):

If you want fresh baked goodness, then you need to store the dough, either refrigerated or frozen.  (If you're going to freeze it, portion and shape the dough first so you don't have to scoop frozen dough.)

I sometimes store cookies in an airtight bin at room temperature for up to 3 or 4 days.  They're not fresh baked at that point, but still good.  For longer storage of baked cookies, I use the freezer.  You can keep them frozen in a zip top freezer bag for months.  Reheating is optional.  Eating a chocolate chip cookie (or, even better, a chocolate chip raisin oatmeal pecan cookie) fresh from the freezer is a very different experience from eating a warm cookie, but it's lovely in its own way.